# Why printing in color in a Windows terminal in Python does not work?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, terminal

I can print test1 in green and test2 in red in ipython :

```
print ('\033[92m' + "test1")
print ('\033[91m' + "test2")
```

But gives me the following error printed in white in the terminal :

```
[92mtest1
[91mtest2
```

Comment: `pip install pygments`?

Comment: thanks it works with colorama

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows terminal doesn't handle ansi coding for coloring text like other (vt100 compatible) terminals. If you want to be able to color your output in windows your best bet is likely going to be something like [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama), [Ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) or some other external program to handle colorizing output to the windows terminal.

Comment: thanks it works with Colorama

Comment: Except the Windows 10 console does support virtual terminal sequences. It can be enabled by default for all console windows by setting a "VirtualTerminalLevel" REG_DWORD with a value of 1 in the registry key "HKCU\Console".